# Create database in separate partition or new drive in mysql

Tags: mysql-5.6

We are using MySQL 5.6 having all databases in 1 partition /usr/local/mysql.

Now we want to create a new database which is of large size. But the existing partition is not having enough space and one more limitation is we are not able to add additional space to the existing mysql partition (usr/local/mysql).

I came to know about tablespace feature in MySQL. (creating a new tablespace in new partition and create all the tables pointing to the new tablespace). By this, all the tables and data will be using/creating in same tablespace.

Do using of same tablespace is good standard ? This may again loose the feature of innodb_file_per_table right ?

Are there any other ways to create new databases in new partitions/drives without disturbing the existing databases ?

Comment: technically I think you can mount a filesystem on '/usr/local/mysql/{databasename}', should work but I've never needed to.

Comment: The solution with `innodb_file_per_table` set (default in v.5.6.6+) and specifying a tablespace for each separate table (do not forget to set `DATA DIRECTORY` attribute!) seems to be more safe.